# Change directory in batch file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to changed directory using batch file in PowerShell.

Let's say the batch file named go.bat has the two lines of code. And I'm in q: directory.

```
   c:
   cd c:\abc\def
```

When I run `go.bat`, I'm still in q:

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you running a .bat file from PowerShell and expecting it to change the PWD of the PowerShell host?

Comment: When you run a .bat file, the batch file runs in a child cmd.exe process. It won't change the directory of the parent PowerShell process.

Comment: A `.ps1` file is a PowerShell script, not what is commonly known as a batch (or command file) which is interpreted by `command.exe` and has a `.bat` or `.cmd` file extension.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that what you're doing should work, you can always try the Powershell cmdlet "set-location".  It basically works the same way:

```
set-location c:\abc\def
```

Comment: @set-location works but it doesn't work when I run the command in batch file.

Answer (score 5):

When you run a batch file, PowerShell creates a CMD.EXE process to run the file.  If you change the working directory inside the CMD.EXE process, it won't affect the current working directory of PowerShell.  This is by design.

Comment: Is there any way using PowerShell to change this behaviour, to execute the bat file within the active CMD.EXE process?

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered this problem, I wanted to have a script for jumping to a directory which works in Powershell and CMD.

I could solve it by creating a script with the same name, one is a powershell script and the other a bat file:

**Powershell**

```
Set-Location C:\abc\def
```

**Batch**

```
cd C:\abc\def
```

Let us say the script is just called "def". If I type def in Powershell, it will run the ps1 version, if I type it in cmd, it will run the bat. You have to have duplicate files but you get to use the same named command between shells.

Comment: This was what I had to do. The cd nor cd /D command does not work from a bat in PS. Nor can we call Set-Location in PS from a batch.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that C:\abc\def exists?

On my machine starting from the E: drive

- C:
- cd C:\windows\system32

works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   cd /D c:\abc\def
```

Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current
directory for a drive -- although I'm not sure why what you tried isn't working...

If the folder doesn't exist you'll get an error message:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

You can view some help on the `cd` command by typing `cd /?`.

Answer (score 0):

In batch you can’t change to UNC path for example:

cd \192.169.10.15\work_dir

In that case powershell can do it.