# simple batch script not working PS, but works in cmd

Tags: windows, batch, powershell

I have a .bat script that just cds into a directory

**cddocs.bat**

```
cd \Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\
```

It is in my home folder. (`C:\Users\Me`)

In `cmd` when I run it

```
C:\Users\Me>cddocs
C:\Users\Me>cd \Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\
C:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\>
```

It works as expected, I'm in the NetBeans directory. In powershell, I get this

```
PS C:\Users\Me> .\cddocs

C:\Users\Me>cd \Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\
PS C:\Users\Me>
```

So it appears to run the `cd` command, but I am still in my home directory! I must be missing something really simple here. **How can I get this tiny script to actually cd the directory in powershell?**

Comment: Turns out someone already asked this.

Comment: Also related (basically a duplicate): [Making PowerShell assume the working directory of a called Batch file](http://superuser.com/questions/685476/making-powershell-assume-the-working-directory-of-a-called-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

Your powershell environment is launching your script in a cmd batch context.

In this context, the script is changing his current directory (with your 'cd' command). After that, the script exits.

When the script exits of the cmd batch context, the context is destroyed and you come back in the initial powershell context which did not change it's current directory.

Comment: so that explains the why, however, how can I create a script to change the directory in the "PS" context?

Comment: "how can I create a script to change the directory in the "PS" context"  Write a PowerShell script (`.ps1`) instead of trying to use a batch file?