# .bat file to move to directory not running on Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In my powershell profile, I set the line to my C: drive: `set-location c:\`. However, I used to use my path variable `github` to jump to my github folder. This worked on command line, and my other non cd commands work on Powershell, just not this one.

```
:: move from user space to github folder

@echo off
cd users
cd giaco
cd documents
cd github
```

It simply ignores the command:

[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxdzj.png)

However, when I use another command:

[jekyll build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scb7s.png)

It works fine.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Use instead `cd /d "C:\users\giaco\documents\github"` if the current location isn't where you expect it, all your relative cd commands don't work.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks, however isn't working: https://imgur.com/a/k2ON2R6 still in the same directory.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change directory in batch file with PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/398072/change-directory-in-batch-file-with-powershell)

Comment: You simply can't change the current location in powershell from a spawned batch, after closing the batch the cd doesn't persist. Why don't issue a `Set-Location "C:\users\giaco\documents\github"` in powershell?